# How to set Priority Order of displaying context param parameters on server?

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get the parameters names in a Servlet Context object from context param elements in an order given in the web.xml file. But on running code on the server, displayed parameter order is not the same as to mention in the web.xml file.

```
DemoServlet.java

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();

    ServletContext context=getServletContext();

    //we are getting all the initialization parameter from the web.xml file
    Enumeration<String> e=context.getInitParameterNames();



    while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s=e.nextElement();
        pw.println("<br>"+context.getInitParameter(s));
        }

    pw.close();
    }

}


web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Servlet6ServletContextInterface2</display-name>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>DemoServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>DriverName</param-name>
  <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>Username</param-name>
  <param-value>Pranay Singh</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>Password</param-name>
  <param-value>abc123</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/context</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Expected Results:

> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Pranay Singh abc123

Actual Results:

> Pranay Singh  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  abc123

Answer (score 0):

The params are intended to be accessed by their name, so the orders are not guaranteed.

If you really need them in a specific order, you can hard-code the param names (in your own order) into a collection:

```
List<String> paramNames = Arrays.asList("DriverName", "Username", "Password");

for(String paramName: paramNames) {
    pw.println("<br>" + context.getInitParameter(paramName));
}
```

Or if you want to keep the params dynamic without hard-coding anything, you can at least sort them.

```
Enumeration<String> e = context.getInitParameterNames();
List<String> paramNames = Collections.list(e);
Collections.sort(paramNames);

for(String paramName: paramNames) {
    pw.println("<br>" + context.getInitParameter(paramName));
}
```